# Getting wrong month number from java calender

Tags: java

I am trying to fetching current month as int from calender but getting wrong month number.

I have used below code :

```
public static Date getTodayDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return calendar.getTime();
}

private static int getMonthFromDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(getTodayDate());
    return cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
}

public static void main(String[] arps) {
    System.out.println("Current Month in Integer :: " + getMonthFromDate());
}
```

> Output :- Current Month in Integer :: 5
>
> Expected Output  :- Current Month in Integer :: 6

Answer (score 2):

The month in `Calendar` is zero-based, i.e. Jan = 0. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) gives the full details.

Answer (score 0):

***The Months are numbered from 0 (January) to 11 (December).***

**Use**: `System.out.println("Current Month in Integer :: " + getMonthFromDate()+1);`